# How to arrange data from columns A:G to G:A

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to paste a data from Excel to Google Sheet. Current data in column is 2022 to 2017 (column B to G), and I just want to get the data in column as 2017 to 2022. I want just paste the new data and the data arranged in the 2017 to 2022.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the CHOOSECOLS function

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A:G,7,6,5,4,3,2,1)
```

Or if you want it dynamic

```
=CHOOSECOLS(A:G,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:G),1,-1,-1))
```

Comment: =CHOOSECOLS(A:G,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A:G),1,-1,-1)) 
this is perfect! Thank you, z..

Answer (score 3):

### Flip Columns

**Your Case (Your Screenshot)**

```
=LET(data,A1:G7,first_column,2,
    c,COLUMNS(data),sa,SEQUENCE(,c),
CHOOSECOLS(data,IF(sa<first_column,sa,
    SEQUENCE(,c,c+first_column-1,-1))))
```

**Another Case**

[image]

```
=LET(data,A1:H6,first_column,3,
    c,COLUMNS(data),sa,SEQUENCE(,c),
CHOOSECOLS(data,IF(sa<first_column,sa,
    SEQUENCE(,c,c+first_column-1,-1))))
```

**How?**

- First, create an ascending sequence (`sa`) of the number of all columns.

  ```
  =SEQUENCE(,8)
  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
  ```
- Then create a descending sequence (`sd`) of the number of all columns increased by the first flip column minus one.

  ```
  =SEQUENCE(,8,8+3-1,-1)
  10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3
  ```
- Using the `IF` function, from the first sequence, take all first numbers that are less than the first flip column, and from the 2nd sequence, take the rest of the numbers to create the required sequence.

  ```
  =IF(sa<3,sa,sd)
  1,2,8,7,6,5,4,3
  ```

Comment: I needed a couple  of mods to make it work in Google Sheets: =ArrayFormula(LET(data,A1:G7,first_column,2,
    c,COLUMNS(data),sa,SEQUENCE(1,c),
CHOOSECOLS(data,IF(sa<first_column,sa,
    SEQUENCE(1,c,c+first_column-1,-1)))))